# Whisper not showing old data

Tags: graphite, whisper, graphite-carbon

I have set retention policy as 10s:1d 1m:7d 15m:1y. But using this when I try to get one month data nothing is shown on graphite. Only last 24 hrs of data is shown.

I tried to change retention policy to 1m:31d,15m:1y,1h:5y and running whisper-resize.py with --xFilesFactor=0.0 but no luck. I have also restarted carbon-cache.py.

Also after this change, I checked count.wsd file using whisper-info for older dates but it shows None. Using whisper-dump it shows 0 for old dates.

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was due to /opt/graphite/conf/storage-aggregation.conf not present. I looked in carbon logs it was showing /

> opt/graphite/conf/storage-aggregation.conf not found, ignoring

I guess old data is not available now. :(

---

After enabling this also, data was retained in graphite more than 24 hrs. After digging more it turns out that datapoints required for aggregation were less. So I changed xFilesFactor=0.0 and resized whisper files again..

Now it is retaining old data points as well.